# My kitchen lights won't turn on, what could be the problem?

Tags: lighting

My kitchen light will not turn on, even after I replaced all 4 bulbs. What could be the problem? The breaker is working fine, all the plugs and other lights are working in the proper condition, and GFCI switches were all reset.

Do I need to replace the entire unit?

Comment: What type of light fixture is it?  Incandescent bulbs, florescent tubes, CFL, LEDs, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming florescent lights, the most likely cause is a failed ballast. Generally a bulb or socket issue will only affect 1 or 2 lights, not all 4.

Replacing a ballast is pretty straight forward and just requires re-connecting the necessary wires.  Make sure you note the old ballast type, as well as the bulb types and wattages when selecting a replacement.

If it is an older fixture with T-12 bulbs, you will most likely need to replace the ballast and bulbs with newer T8 bulbs that are more energy efficient.

Comment: I've found that often it's cheaper for an entire new fixture vs just the ballast (particularly if you find something on sale). YMMV, and of course, you may want to pay extra to keep the existing fixtures because you really like them, or because they're installed in a way that is difficult to change.

Answer (score 0):

Florescent ceiling lights, I assume?  The transformer might be burned out, tends to happen on the older florescent ceiling lights eventually.

If you have a voltmeter, (carefully) check if the bulb sockets are showing a voltage.